# How to fetch the data from the url if the response coming is opaque. mode: "no-cors" is not showing any effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While fetching the link response should be give me an array of two values but here response is showing as bellow.
Response in the console:
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}

```
  index.js:1 Error: Error: Could not fetch user roles data!
  at fetchData (role-actions.js:12)
  at async role-actions.js:21

**code:**
export const fetchRoleData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.saaspect.com/user/roles", {
    mode: "no-cors",
    });
    console.log("response", response);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Could not fetch user roles data!");
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
    };

    try {
      const roles = await fetchData();
      console.log("inside try");
      dispatch(
        uiActions.showUserRoles({
          userRoles: roles.items || [],
        })
      );
   } catch (error) {
     console.error("Error:", error);
   }
 };
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Opaque means that the response is a box you can't see inside.

`mode: 'no-cors'` is only useful is you need to send a request and *not* see the response.

If you want to look inside it you will need `mode: 'cors'` and permission (as per the CORS specification) from the server to read the response.

Comment: If I try to access it with mode:"cors" or withur any method it is giving like           
 Access to fetch at 'https://api.saaspect.com/user/roles' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: @Soumya — Yes? As I said an an opaque response **doesn't** serve your needs and you need permission from `api.saaspect.com` as per the CORS spec.

Comment: Okayy then it seems I can't fetch it